# if else in where clause on columns

Tags: sql

I have a situation where we have added a new column current_owner (createdBy is already there).
Now I want to write a query such that in where clause if current_owner is null then condition applied on createdBy or else on current_owner.

```
select * 
from wns 
where (if current_owner==null then createdBy = ? else current_owner = ?)
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Use a CASE: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE

Comment: Will take care @forpas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM wns 
WHERE ? = COALESCE(current_owner, createdBy);
```

PS. In DBMS with strong datatypes system you must explicitly cast both operands in COALESCE to the same datatype which can be compared with the parameter provided.